# After deploying Angular app to S3 no changes happen

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, web-deployment

After removing all cookies on the browser and trying to reach the website from different computers I can not find my recent changes after 3 hours from the deployment.

Does anyone know why this happens, if this normal or I am missing something?

the following are the build and deployment scripts:

```
script:
    - yarn build --prod --deploy-url / --base-href /
    - aws s3 sync dist/ s3://${PROD_BUCKET_NAME}/ --delete
```

Comment: Hard refresh helps: SHIFT + F5?

Comment: No cache clearing, hard refresh Ctrl+Shift+R doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a AWS CloudFront caching which is causing this problem since I'm using AWS CF so the solution to this is either **invalidate** files or use **versioning**.

Here is the detailed docs about this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html